# Change the colour of bubbles in Google visualization motion chart

Tags: api, graph, visualization

I there a way where by I can **define** the colours of bubbles in a motion chart provided by Google visualization API ? I do not want to use the **default** colour scheme.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've not found an inbuilt way to do this. However, what you can do is assign each bubble a "colour" variable.  Then you can set the colour of the bubbles to this variable.  I have found that for 3 bubbles, setting one to 1, another to 1.5 and the third to 3 projects reasonable well (on the default colour scheme, yellow projects very poorly).  This approach gives you limited control over the colour scheme.

Comment: Thank you for taking out time to address this Andrew. I will try this out soon.

Comment: I've got an example but don't have enough kudos to post the picture. When I get chance I'll upload it onto my blog and put a link here.

Answer (score 0):

It's 2017 and I have yet to find a good update for this. So here is the solution I came up with. HTH.

```
#views.py
# Bubble Chart: ID, X, Y Color, Size
data.append(['ID', 'X', 'Y', 'Category', 'Z'])
data.append(['', 0, 0, 'Cat 1', 0]) #<-- the order of 
data.append(['', 0, 0, 'Cat 2', 0]) #<-- these fakeout items
data.append(['', 0, 0, 'Cat 3', 0]) #<-- is important
data.append(['', 0, 0, 'Cat 4', 0]) #<-- Blue, Red, Orange, Green - in that order
```

... for r in source:
       data.append(r.a, r.b, r.c, r.d, r.e)

```
return render(
    request,
    'Template.html',
    {
        'title':'',
        'year':datetime.now().year,
        'org': org,
        'data': json.dumps(data),
    }

#in the scripts block of template.html

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

    function drawChart() {

        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable({{data|safe}});

        var options = {
            title: 'Bubble By Category Strategy',
            hAxis: { title: 'X', ticks: [{v: 0, f:''}, {v: 1, f:'L'}, {v: 2, f:'M'}, {v: 3, f:'H'}, {v: 4, f:''}] },
            vAxis: { title: 'Y', ticks: [{v: 0, f:''}, {v: 1, f:'L'}, {v: 2, f:'M'}, {v: 3, f:'H'}, {v: 4, f:''}]  },
            bubble: {
                textStyle: {
                    fontSize: 11,
                    fontName: 'Lato',
                }
            }
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.BubbleChart(document.getElementById('riskChart'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
    }

</script>
```